# Android: Preference values to textview from preferences.xml

Tags: android, xml, preferences

I have a preference xml in xml/preferences.xml:

```
    <EditTextPreference
    android:key="welcome_message"
    android:title="Welcome message" 
    android:summary="Default welcome message"
    android:dialogTitle="Tervetuloa-viesti"
    android:dialogMessage="Input"    
    android:defaultValue="Default message" />
```

I know how to get the welcome_message from the preferences by code, but can I do it in XML something like:

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="(INCLUDE welcome_message HERE)" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in my main.xml and if so, how? Thanks.

Comment: you can't do it via xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't directly reference preference value from xml layout.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll have to use the other way.